# The Outgoing and Reply port of STUN message?

Tags: pjsip, stun

I'm trying to implement something with STUN (with PJSIP) as following flow:

[IE] <--TCP/UDP trans.--> [agentC] <----STUN-----> [agentS] <--UDP/TCP trans.--> [Apache]

And the [TCP/UDP trans.] part is ready.

The agentC might have the stun mapped address 1.1.1.1:11111

while agentS might have the stun mapped address 2.2.2.2:22222

Now agentC send a [HTTP GET] to agentS:

Question:

1. What will be the outgoing port of agentC? will it through NAT port 11111 or will be a random port[ex:37654]?

2.How should the agent reply the html tags? Reply to the 11111 or the previous port[ex:37654]?

3.If the agentC is behind a symmetric NAT (while agentS behind a full cone),could agentC connect to agentS and could agentS reply to agentC?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense.
What is "TCP/UDP trans." in the above diagram?  Given that HTTP is ALWAYS on TCP, how do you expect IE to communicate with agentC over UDP?  Is agentS on the same machine as the Apache server?

Comment: You may just want to edit the question with more elaboration.

Comment: @selbie. Hi, maybe I'm not very good in present something,but you can check this http://code.google.com/p/udptunnel/ .   I just want to replace normal UDP with STUN